# Android Widgets and Layouts Defaults

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I'm having trouble finding the answer (overwhelmed with search hits).

Where can I find the source code to the default settings of the various built-in layouts and widgets?

Why? So I can see what they (the android developers) are doing so that I can emulate when I like, and change what I don't.  There are hundreds, if not thousands of files in my API, so going through them one-by-one is...tedious at best.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is in at the [Android Git Repository](http://android.git.kernel.org/) at kernel.org in repository [platform/frameworks/base.git](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree). Clone this repository, as it is far less frustrating not waiting for it to load via the Internet. The View related code is a couple different packages, [android.view](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/view), [android.widget](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree), and [android.webkit](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;f=core/java/android/webkit;). The the related XML resources are scattered a bit wider but to start take a look at [values](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree) and [drawable](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=tree;) directories.

Comment: Is this the only place to find this?  I was hoping it'd be part of the API.

Comment: Some of it is but most of it is not.